# IPTables forward traffic without hiding source IP

Tags: iptables, forward, gateway

I am trying to setup a cloud server as a gateway, which forwards all traffic to my second cloud server. The problem is that the destination server (2nd cloud) only sees the IP address of the first cloud server.

Is it possible to keep the source IP so it would show the IP address of the one connecting to the first cloud server. I have tried removing MASQUERADE, but the connection between cloud #1 -> cloud #2 did not work properly anymore.

> -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
>
> -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>
> -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination DESTINATIONIP:PORT
>
> -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

It works with this setup, but does not show the source IP. Have you got any idea on how to not hide the IP that is connecting to the first cloud server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

cloud 1 and 2 need to be in same network, a VPN is fine

on cloud1:

```
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination DESTINATIONIP:PORT
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

on cloud2, we mark the desired packet with 1, eth0 is the default gateway:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 25565 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

you need to manipulate the routing table on cloud2:
edit /etc/iproute2/rt_tables, add the line

```
1 http
```

here the manipulation, tun0 is the vpn interface on cloud2:

```
ip route add default via ip_vpn_cloud1 dev tun0 table http
ip rule add from all fwmark 1 table http
```

be sure that net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter and net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter are set to 1 in /etc/sysctl.conf

Answer (score -1):

With -A POSTROUTING  -j MASQUERADE all outgoing forwarded packets will have the source IP of the corresponding outgoing interface.

You should be more specific on the packets you masquerade/SNAT.